# What does s~ do in Perl?

Tags: perl

A Perl file I'm using contains many instances of `s~`. I'm not familiar with Perl and am having a hard time finding info on it. I know it's related to a search and replace string. What does `s~` do exactly?

Example:

```
s~ (Text)~ <a href="../images/text.pdf" target="_top">$1</a>~ig if /<p/;
```

Comment: Added links (to the duplicate closure) that tightly relate to this question

Comment: I don’t think this should be marked as a dupe. Those other questions pre-suppose you know what this operator is doing. This question is basically “what is this?”, and it’s a fair question for someone who doesn’t know what it’s called and therefore how to look it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `s` is the substitution operator. It's used like `$str =~ s/this/that/` to change an occurrence of "this" to "that" in `$str`.

While `/` is the most common delimiter, `s` uses whatever non-whitespace character immediately follows to set the delimiter to use in the rest of the expression. (This is true of many other operators, such as `m`, `q`, etc., as well.)

This example says to replace the text  `(Text)` with an HTML anchor element, using the `i` and `g` flags.

The reason to use `~` rather than the conventional `/` is to avoid the need to escape the `/` in the replacement text, like

```
s/ (Text)/ <a href="..\/images\/text.pdf" target="_top">$1<\/a>/ig if /<p/;
```

More details can be found by running `perldoc -f s`.